# Jquery change html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have structure like this:

```
<div id="mali_oglasi">
    <?php foreach ($mgs as $key) : ?>
    <p class="mali_oglas">
        <span class="name"><?php echo $key['name'] ?></span>
        <span class="body"><?php echo $key['body'] ?></span>
        <span class="contact_author"><?php echo $key['contact_author'] ?></span>
        <span class="date_created"><?php echo $key['date_created'] ?></span>
        <span class="date_expires"><?php echo $key['date_expires'] ?></span>
        <span class="email"><?php echo $key['email'] ?></span>
    <?php foreach ($lokacija as $lok) : ?>
    <?php if($lok['id_location'] == $key['location_id']) : ?>
    <span><?php echo $lok['name'] ?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($kategorija as $kat) : ?>
    <?php if($kat['id_category'] == $key['category_id']) : ?>
    <span><?php echo $kat['name'] ?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <a class="obrisi" id="<?php echo $key['id_global_info'] ?>">Obrisi</a>     
    <a class="izmeni" id="<?php echo $key['id_global_info'] ?>">Izmeni</a>  
</p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

When `<a class="izmeni" id="<?php echo $key['id_global_info'] ?>">Izmeni</a>` is clicked it need to change span to input or textarea. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use jQuerys [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)-method. E.g.

```
$('.izmeni').on('click', function() {
    $('span').replaceWith('<input />');
});
```

You can also walk up the DOM in your click handler to get to your target element:

```
$('.izmeni').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('span').replaceWith('<input />');

    // or:
    //  $(this).closest('p').find('span').replaceWith('<input />');
    // etc.
});
```

Or something similar. Take a look at jQuerys various [tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: It is working but I want to target just spans within a single <p class="mali_oglasi"> (parent of the clicked element).

Comment: Code from above is creating multyple <p> tags, and I need to target span in the specific <p> tag (parent).

Comment: In your click handler you are free to traverse the DOM tree as you like. I added another example to my answer. See the jQuery tree traversal functions for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<?php echo $key['id_global_info'] ?>').click(function() {
       $(selectorforspan).html('the new html');
    });
});
```

This could use the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to set the HTML contents of the element specified in the selector (`$(selectorforspan)`).

Comment: @gdoron nope it will replace - read the docs -> "When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content."

Comment: that's right, but he wrote he wants to replace the `<span>` not it's content... though he probably didn't mean it.

Comment: @gdoron I read his question differently !! but I really have no idea what the OP is trying to do !!!! replacing a `span` with an `input` ... why !??!

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$('a.izmeni').click(function(){
    $('span.classofyourspan').replaceWith($('<input>', { type : "text", name: "yourname"}));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do, but using jQuery's replaceWith method looks like the best way. There's even an example on their documentation: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

```
$('.izmeni').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<span>'+$(this).text()+'</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.izmeni').live('click', function() {
 var span = $('p.mali_oglasi span');
 var inputBox = $('<input />').attr('value', span.text());

 span.replaceWith(inputBox);
});
```